# What does the N mean?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have seen many SP like:

```
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @max_titleOUT = max(JobTitle) 
                 FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee
                 WHERE BusinessEntityID = @level';
```

What exactly does that N mean?

Comment: `n`  or `N` refers to Unicode... It means that the text in the variable uses Unicode.  It also means that the size of the variable is 2 bytes per character instead of 1 byte per char like a varchar() variable would be.  But if the variable was previously declared as a Unicode variable  (`declare @sqlString nVarchar(200)`),  then I don't think you need to prefix the string literal with the `N`.

Comment: You don't need to prefix *this* string, but you *should* prefix a string that contains any characters that won't encode well when converting to unicode.

Comment: N is the abbreviation of N[ational] word and it reprezents UNICODE string constants.

Answer (score 3):

Using this prefix indicates that the string is unicode

Comment: There is already a waaaaaay better answer in the comments, and this should have been in there too. While it answers the question, you should have explained it more and possibly provided links to MSDN artices etc.